# Incorrect information in .frm file after a power outage?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, linux, partitioning

- CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
- x86_64
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

**SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G**:

```
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 1696
                   Last_Error: Error executing row event: 'Failed to read from the .par file'
```

**/var/log/mysqld.log**:

```
130706  2:26:04 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Incorrect information in file: './reportingdb/v3_ban_date.frm'
130706  2:26:04 [ERROR] Slave SQL: Error executing row event: 'Failed to read from the .par file', Error_code: 1696
130706  2:26:04 [Warning] Slave: Failed to read from the .par file Error_code: 1696
130706  2:26:04 [Warning] Slave: Incorrect information in file: './reportingdb/v3_ban_date.frm' Error_code: 1033
```

`v3_ban_date` is a partitioned table. The `.par` file is... empty:

```
# ls -l v3_ban_date.par
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 0 Jul  6 01:54 v3_ban_date.par
```

and this is the `.frm` format (`hexdump -v -C v3_ban_date.frm`):

```
|partition.... PA|
|RTITION BY RANGE|
| (TO_DAYS(dt)).(|
|PARTITION p00 VA|
|LUES LESS THAN (|
|0) ENGINE = Inno|
|DB,. PARTITION p|
|1 VALUES LESS TH|
|AN (734653) ENGI|
|NE = InnoDB,. PA|
|RTITION p02 VALU|
|ES LESS THAN (73|
|4745) ENGINE = I|
|nnoDB,. PARTITIO|
|N p031 VALUES LE|
|SS THAN (734863)|
| ENGINE = InnoDB|
|,. PARTITION p04|
| VALUES LESS THA|
|N (734959) ENGIN|
|E = InnoDB,. PAR|
|TITION p05 VALUE|
|S LESS THAN (735|
|103) ENGINE = In|
|noDB,. PARTITION|
| p06 VALUES LESS|
| THAN (735160) E|
|NGINE = InnoDB,.|
| PARTITION p07 V|
|ALUES LESS THAN |
|(735210) ENGINE |
|= InnoDB,. PARTI|
|TION MERGER_2013|
|324 VALUES LESS |
|THAN (735316) EN|
|GINE = InnoDB,. |
|PARTITION pcurre|
|nt_2013324 VALUE|
|S LESS THAN (735|
|317) ENGINE = In|
|noDB,. PARTITION|
| MERGER_201375 V|
|ALUES LESS THAN |
|(735419) ENGINE |
|= InnoDB,. PARTI|
|TION pcurrent_20|
|1375 VALUES LESS|
| THAN (735420) E|
|NGINE = InnoDB).|
```

The partition definitions on the first slave looks like this:

```
00000000  1f 00 00 00 74 00 01 07  0c 00 00 00 0c 0c 0c 0c  |....t...........|
00000010  0c 0c 0c 0c 0c 0c 0c 0c  60 00 00 00 70 30 30 00  |........`...p00.|
00000020  70 31 00 70 30 32 00 70  30 33 31 00 70 30 34 00  |p1.p02.p031.p04.|
00000030  70 30 35 00 70 30 36 00  70 30 37 00 4d 45 52 47  |p05.p06.p07.MERG|
00000040  45 52 5f 32 30 31 33 33  32 34 00 70 63 75 72 72  |ER_2013324.pcurr|
00000050  65 6e 74 5f 32 30 31 33  33 32 34 00 4d 45 52 47  |ent_2013324.MERG|
00000060  45 52 5f 32 30 31 33 38  32 38 00 70 63 75 72 72  |ER_2013828.pcurr|
00000070  65 6e 74 5f 32 30 31 33  38 32 38 00              |ent_2013828.|
0000007c
```

I've tried to copy this file to the second slave, then used [`bvi`](http://bvi.sourceforge.net/) to edit the date to `201375` (corresponding with what is in the `.frm` file), then tried to start the second slave, but it didn't work.

So the questions are:

1. How do I know what information is incorrect in the `.frm` file?
2. Can I re-create the `.par` file from the one on the first slave?

PS: I know I can rebuild the second slave but I think this is an interesting challenge.